# Получение исходного пароля пользователя

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

После регистрации пользователя Spring Security шифрует его пароль. Каким образом в дальнейшем можно получить исходный пароль для его редактирования?

Comment: никак, не получится

Comment: для редактирования вводят новый, при этом старый вводят

Comment: почитайте про хеширование. пароли хранить не принято, вместо этого хранят хеш и именно его сравнивают с хешом введенного пароля. хеш назад преобразовать невозможно. но зато при слабом алгоритме хеширования вы становитесь уязвимы для брутфорса, ведь фактически теперь не надо знать настоящий пароль, надо лишь подобрать комбинацию, хеш которой совпадет с хешом пароля (это называется коллизией). посему чем слабее алгоритм хеширования, тем менее ресурсозатратно его считать, но тем больше коллизий и, соответствеено, легче его взломать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сегодняшний день ни одна нормальная система не хранит пароль в восстанавливаемом виде. Применяют алгоритмы хеширования без восстановления.

Comment: зашифрованное по определению всегда можно восстановить... подберите другое слово, например, хеширование